# Combine two files on linux based on the same column in Linux file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I want to combine 2 files into one file based on the same column on Linux.

File1.txt

```
100005 10.15.122.22
101000 10.15.122.13
103002 10.15.119.15
103003 10.15.119.19
109000 10.15.116.17
109001 10.15.116.32
101010 10.15.116.33
110000 10.15.116.20
110001 10.15.116.19
110003 10.15.116.16
110004 10.15.124.11
110005 10.15.116.15
110011 10.15.116.25
102005 10.15.116.18
```

File2.txt

```
101005  John
101006  Maria
101007  Molly
101008  Ringo
101009  Paul
101010  Randy
102001  Sam
102002  Erick
102003  Owen
102004  Bryan
102005  Annie
102006  Sameer
```

And I want the result as follows:

```
101005 10.15.122.22 John
101010 10.15.116.33 Randy
102005 10.15.116.1  Annie
```

How to do that?

Comment: Could you please do add your efforts in your question and let us know then, on SO we do encourage users to do so.

Comment: Also could you please double check your expected output `100005 10.15.122.22 John` looks like this should NOT be there in expected output? Kindly confirm on same.

Comment: [`join`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html) is your friend. I don't see why you should be expecting John in your results , though.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, Thank you for your correction. I mistyped and the result should like **101005 10.15.122.22 John**

Comment: @Shawn, Oh yes I already use join command and here is my command: 
`join -1 1 -2 1 file1.txt file2.txt`
but the result is 
**join: file1.txt:7: is not sorted: 101010 10.15.116.33**

Comment: Yup, you have to make sure the files are sorted based on the join column, just like the man page says. Your first one isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} a[$1]{print $0,a[$1]}'  file2  file1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code here.

```
awk '             ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{          ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which will be TRUE for first Input_file then do following.
  a[$1]=$2        ##Creating an array a with index $1 and value $2 here.
  next            ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
a[$1]{            ##Checking condition if array a with index $1 is NOT NULL then do following.
  print $0,a[$1]  ##Printing current line along with array a with index $1 value here.
}
'  file2  file1   ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: The result is correct but i still don't know about the logic. Would you mind if you explain it?

Comment: @arieffirdaus, Sure adding explanation in few mins now.

Comment: @arieffirdaus, Please check my updated answer with detailed explanation and lemme know then?

Comment: @arieffirdaus, your welcome, glad to help.

Answer (score 6):

This should do the task. First you sort the columns and then use join command.

```
join <(sort f1.txt) <(sort f2.txt)
```